# Editing list of numbers that inside list of names

Tags: list-manipulation

I have list of names like

**listname**=[data1, runner, day, weather]

The values within the list of names are also lists themselves (numbers and names).
like

**data1**=[38,40,5,16,52]

**day**=[Sunday, Monday]

Which command is used to edit the internal list using the external list?

like use **listname** to change values inside **data1**?

I add parts of the code what is the result:

input

```
validFN
validFN[[1, 3]]
ratio1hive1bee1repeat1[[3]]
```

output

```
{"ratio1hive1bee1repeat1", "ratio1hive1bee1repeat2","ratio1hive1bee1repeat3"}
{"ratio1hive1bee1repeat1", "ratio1hive1bee1repeat2","ratio1hive1bee1repeat3"}[[1, 3]]
{"00:00:00.220", -1, -3, -0.059234, -0.118468, 243, 0.132451,0.252855, 1.26427, "center"}
```

I'm really not an expert, with very little programming knowledge at all.

I think the names in the list **validFN** are only names, and the code does not recognize that there is a list with the same name defined earlier. Of course there is a high probability that I also make a mistake in semantics

Comment: Are these python lists?

Comment: No, The lists I have used here are just examples. one of them are CSV list that I import to the notebook and the others I built in Mathematica

Comment: @erez, what Syed probably meant is, the examples you gave are not in correct Mathematica syntax. Lists in Mathematica are enclosed in curly braces (`{ ... }`). Can you show the exact code you are using in Mathematica ? Edit your question to include it by using the edit link under the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have this situation:

```
data1 = {38, 40, 5, 16, 52};
day = {Sunday, Monday};
runner = "runner";
weather = "weather";
listname = {data1, runner, day, weather}
(* output:
   {{38, 40, 5, 16, 52}, "runner", {Sunday, Monday}, "weather"}*)
```

and you want the 5 to be changed to 999, you could do this:

```
listname[[1, 3]] = 999
```

However, it's not clear that this is what you really want. This will change the value of listname, but it won't change the value of data1. Mathematica doesn't use references. If in addition to the above, you also do this:

```
data1[[4]] = 999
```

then listname remains as it was. Specifically, after all of these operations, you'll have

```
listname == {{38, 40, 999, 16, 52}, "runner", {Sunday, Monday}, "weather"}
```

and

```
data1 == {38, 40, 5, 999, 52}
```